# What is wrong with the following logical if or statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, it must be very basic:

```
if (controllerName === ('about' || 'contact' || 'lessons')) {
        res.render(controllerName + '.ejs', locals);
    }
```

Only when `controllerName=='about'` I go inside, the rest of the cases I don't.

How do the `or` and `===` operate in this case ?

Comment: the javascript interpreter will not perform deMorgans for you.

Comment: Conditional expressions are explicit rather than idiomatic. You need to evaluate each one independently. It makes perfect sense to say in your mind "controllerName equals about or contact or lessons", but the expression needs you to spell it out completely.

Comment: @jbabey i had no idea that was called deMorgans law. thanks for the trivia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You structured it incorrectly. A fix would be

```
if (controllerName == 'about' || controllerName == 'contact' || controllerName == 'lessons') {
    res.render(controllerName + '.ejs', locals);
}
```

The problem was that `('about' || 'contact' || 'lessons')` evaluates to `about` since it is the first non-(null/undefined) value in the set. It seems like you want to compare `controllerName` to all three values so notice how my version of your code compares `controllerName` to all three values separately.

Comment: -0.49 for mentioning w3schools.

Comment: `||` says if the expression on the left is truthy, return it. Else return the expression on the right. That's all it does.

Comment: didn't know people hated w3schools. Thats some interesting stuff so I've removed it.

Comment: thanks @AlexWayne for clarifying the `||`. I've updated my answer with this in mind

Comment: Hating W3Schools became too mainstream nowadays. I'd even defend it for such basic learning which is hard to find detailed info, until I saw the terrible indentation they use in that page. Gawsh.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  All the info of w3schools, minus about 99% of the obsolescence and outright wrongness.  Add to that, it's from people who actually built a browser, rather than some schmucks trying to sell TP-quality certifications.

Comment: @cHao Agreed, I already link to MDN on most of my JS answers. `=]`

Answer (score 5):

A more concise fix could use a regular expression:

```
if (/^(about|contact|lessons)$/.test(controllerName)) { ... }
```

Comment: Or to be even more specific, `/^(about|contact|lessons)$/`, so it won't match `contact_01` or such.

Answer (score 4):

The logical OR operators work a bit differently than you're using it. The fix would be:

```
if(controllerName === 'about' || 
   controllerName === 'contact' ||
   controllerName === 'lessons')
```

Or, if you wanted something a bit easier on the eyes:

```
if((['about','contact','lessons']).indexOf(controllerName) > -1)
```

The problem with your first statement is that `('about' || 'contact' || 'lessons')` will return the first expression that evaluates to `true`. Since any non-empty string cast to a boolean will evaluate to `true`, "about" is always returned. Therefore, your original statement was equivalent to:

```
if(controllerName === 'about')
```